# 12.04 ALSA error

Tags: 12.04, alsa

My system crashes regularly due to probably the alsa driver. The system suddenly becomes unusable slow, although the music keeps playing. I tried to submit it to the ALSA team, but I can't get in their bug submitting system ...
This is on a HP 8530w with a Intel 82801I (ICH9 Family) HD Audio

```
        Feb 18 21:54:11 laptop pulseaudio[1980]: [alsa-sink] alsa-util.c: snd_pcm_avail() returned a value that is exceptionally large: 404124 bytes (2290 ms).
Feb 18 21:54:11 laptop pulseaudio[1980]: [alsa-sink] alsa-util.c: Most likely this is a bug in the ALSA driver 'snd_hda_intel'. Please report this issue to the ALSA developers.
Feb 18 21:54:11 laptop pulseaudio[1980]: [alsa-sink] alsa-util.c: snd_pcm_dump():
Feb 18 21:54:11 laptop pulseaudio[1980]: [alsa-sink] alsa-util.c: Hardware PCM card 0 'HDA Intel' device 0 subdevice 0
Feb 18 21:54:11 laptop pulseaudio[1980]: [alsa-sink] alsa-util.c: Its setup is:
Feb 18 21:54:11 laptop pulseaudio[1980]: [alsa-sink] alsa-util.c:   stream       : PLAYBACK
Feb 18 21:54:11 laptop pulseaudio[1980]: [alsa-sink] alsa-util.c:   access       : MMAP_INTERLEAVED
Feb 18 21:54:11 laptop pulseaudio[1980]: [alsa-sink] alsa-util.c:   format       : S16_LE
Feb 18 21:54:11 laptop pulseaudio[1980]: [alsa-sink] alsa-util.c:   subformat    : STD
Feb 18 21:54:11 laptop pulseaudio[1980]: [alsa-sink] alsa-util.c:   channels     : 2
Feb 18 21:54:11 laptop pulseaudio[1980]: [alsa-sink] alsa-util.c:   rate         : 44100
Feb 18 21:54:11 laptop pulseaudio[1980]: [alsa-sink] alsa-util.c:   exact rate   : 44100 (44100/1)
Feb 18 21:54:11 laptop pulseaudio[1980]: [alsa-sink] alsa-util.c:   msbits       : 16
Feb 18 21:54:11 laptop pulseaudio[1980]: [alsa-sink] alsa-util.c:   buffer_size  : 16384
Feb 18 21:54:11 laptop pulseaudio[1980]: [alsa-sink] alsa-util.c:   period_size  : 8192
Feb 18 21:54:11 laptop pulseaudio[1980]: [alsa-sink] alsa-util.c:   period_time  : 185759
Feb 18 21:54:11 laptop pulseaudio[1980]: [alsa-sink] alsa-util.c:   tstamp_mode  : ENABLE
Feb 18 21:54:11 laptop pulseaudio[1980]: [alsa-sink] alsa-util.c:   period_step  : 1
Feb 18 21:54:11 laptop pulseaudio[1980]: [alsa-sink] alsa-util.c:   avail_min    : 13034
Feb 18 21:54:11 laptop pulseaudio[1980]: [alsa-sink] alsa-util.c:   period_event : 0
Feb 18 21:54:11 laptop pulseaudio[1980]: [alsa-sink] alsa-util.c:   start_threshold  : -1
Feb 18 21:54:11 laptop pulseaudio[1980]: [alsa-sink] alsa-util.c:   stop_threshold   : 1073741824
Feb 18 21:54:11 laptop pulseaudio[1980]: [alsa-sink] alsa-util.c:   silence_threshold: 0
Feb 18 21:54:11 laptop pulseaudio[1980]: [alsa-sink] alsa-util.c:   silence_size : 0
Feb 18 21:54:11 laptop pulseaudio[1980]: [alsa-sink] alsa-util.c:   boundary     : 1073741824
Feb 18 21:54:11 laptop pulseaudio[1980]: [alsa-sink] alsa-util.c:   appl_ptr     : 113727673
Feb 18 21:54:11 laptop pulseaudio[1980]: [alsa-sink] alsa-util.c:   hw_ptr       : 113812320
```

Comment: It might help to have a screenshot of `alsamixer`.

Answer (score 3):

This is a guess based on [this post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2089143#td_post_12377868)

in terminal, run:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/pulse/client.conf
```

change line nr. 27

from

```
;autospawn = yes
```

to

```
;autospawn = no
```

save, close, see if it helps

if not, revert the client.conf file to its original state and report back